# Scalling UIImage on the screen size

Tags: iphone, uiimage, scaling

I have implemented a small method that imports an picture on the
iPhone screen, but the picture is a little bit to big for the screen.
This is the Method:

```
- (void)ladeImage {
    id path = @"http://172.23.1.63:8080/RestfulJava/pics";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

}
```

But is there any method to scale the picture on the iPhone screen?

Edit1:
Ok thank for your helping, but this method doesn't work, when I switch the iPhone to landscape, her is the code with your tipp:

```
- (void)ladeImage {
    id path = @"http://172.23.1.63:8080/RestfulJava/pics";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    imgView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Edit2:
look this is my class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self ladeImage];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
     if(toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
     { 
         ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
         [self PortraitMode];
     } else if((toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) || (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) { 
         ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320); 
         [self LendscapreMode];
     }
}

- (void)ladeImage {
    id path = @"http://172.23.1.63:8080/RestfulJava/pics";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imgView.frame = self.view.frame;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should insert following code before inserting imageview to the view.

```
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]
```

Also you can set/change from ScaleToFill to AspectFill or as you needed.

and problem will be soved.

Comment: Ok thank for your helping, but this method doesn't work, when i switch the iPhone to landscape, her is the code with your tipp:

- (void)ladeImage {
    id path = @"http://172.23.1.63:8080/RestfulJava/pics";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    imgView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}

Comment: for that you will have to set the frame of the imageview like imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 480,320) for landscape and CGRectmake(0,0, 320,480) for Portrait mode. Hop you'll know how to find landscape and portrait mode method for iphone.

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
 toOrientation= interfaceOrientation;
    return YES;
} before return true write frame for the imgView.

Comment: Sorry i am a total newbie on iPhone engineering and i can't follow your help, i don't know where i have to implement what, sorry :(

Comment: no worries man. simply add above code in your application. make the frame of imageview as I provided. also implement following code if(toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
  {
   ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    //[self PortraitMode];
  }
  else if((toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) || (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
  {
   ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    //[self LendscapreMode];
  } in to the method viewWillAppear

Comment: and this code i have to implement in the class.m where the viewDidLoad of this controller is??

Comment: i have answered down because there is more place :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the frame to the screen size, i.e. imgView.frame = self.view.frame

Comment: Yes that works nearly, but when i turn around the iPhone to landscape, then it isn't on the screen, you understand me?

Answer (score -1):

look this is my class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self ladeImage];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
     if(toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
     { 
         ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
         [self PortraitMode];
     } else if((toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) || (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) { 
         ImgMainPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320); 
         [self LendscapreMode];
     }
}

- (void)ladeImage {
    id path = @"http://172.23.1.63:8080/RestfulJava/pics";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imgView.frame = self.view.frame;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: remove  [self PortraitMode]; and [self LendscapreMode]; it's mine own methods, it will create error

Comment: "answer" is supplement for the question, meanwhile included.